# VirtualBox Ubuntu server guest: serving of symfony app ends up with: attempt denied by server configuration

Tags: php, apache, symfony, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu Server using VirtualBox to develop symfony app. I've set up shared folder, changed apache default folder `/var/www/html` to  `/media/sf_apache_shared` which is shared folder, for convenient development.

The default apache's `index.html` file, denoting that apache is set up correctly, works fine. The problematic moment comes into play, once I try to run symfony app.

If I try to create default symfony app, I get the following result:

[image]

Although I can create symfony app using the same way, but outside of that folder, for example inside of `/var/www/html`.

I've checked the permission of `sf_apache_shared` folder with the result of `770`, using the following command:

```
stat -c %a directory
```

But even aside of that fact, I manually copied symfony app project to `sf_apache_shared` and tried to access that project, from windows host, using chrome. The result apache's logs are:

```
client denied by server configuration: /media/sf_apache_shared/my_project_name/app/
client denied by server configuration: /media/sf_apache_shared/my_project_name/src/
```

Here is my server configuration:

[image]

Comment: Example here http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/igtq/creating-a-symfony-development-environment-with-vagrant uses Virtualbox + Symfony + Vagrant. You can just look into "Create a bootstrap file" section to work out how it is done. You can do all those steps yourself manually. Look at "Create vagrant file" section for synced/shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

i´m not too sure if this will be a final fix for your problem

but you definetly have to set the DocumentRoot and Directory in you conf

to `/media/sf_apache_shared/web`

ins symfony app the /web folder is designed to be the document root

also you should set ServerName and access your server via the hostname

and try Allow from All

example.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName hostname.com
  DocumentRoot "/media/sf_apache_shared/web"
  <Directory "/media/sf_apache_shared/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

also check/compare the owners of the folder (`ls -lrta`)